# Settings variable in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to have an global settings variable for an android application, which is accessable as well from any help java classes without giving them context?!

I try to explain what I mean.

- I have an application version as string value in strings.xml
- I can get its value from every android activity, but not from help java classes withought giving context
- What I do now, is saving it in a static variable of my first activity, but it seems, that sometimes it will be erased and set to null.

May be I do something wrong?!

Sorry for newbie question.

And thank you in advance,

Mur

**P.s.**

I wrote [a small tutorial](http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/static-variable-in-your-android.html) for this topic, to show the solution.

Comment: Why not just pass in the value to the helper classes?

Comment: sorry, but could you explain what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a public static variable in your application class that you fill with the value from strings.xml in the onCreate method. The application class is a singleton and will be the last thing that is killed as part of your app so it will always be there and if you make it public static there will be only one instance.

Comment: That is the answer, which helped me together with this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables). Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

A variable declared as `public`, `static`, and `final` will be visible to all of your classes and never get erased.

```
public static final String VERSION = "1.2.3.4";
```

Comment: it's also +1 from me ... the problem by this solution is, that I'll have two constants, one in string xml, and another one declared as public static final. i want to avoid that and at the same time to have version in string.xml

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have a JAVA class for some common utility functions. You get the value of your string using a context in your Activity/Service and then pass in that value to the JAVA class function as a parameter.

Comment: first it's +1 .. i must look, how much should i change in my application